# Angular bootstrap how to make card of a card-deck to be active when routerlinkactive is true

Tags: css, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular 7 + Bootstrap. I am using bootstrap card deck to create 3 menus.
 When the routerlinkactive is active, I want to style the border for that particular card, where the link is available.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow"> <!-- want to style at this level when link is active -->
      <div class="card-header pb-2">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Menu 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='my-courses' class="link-unstyled">
          <i class="fas fa-tasks fa-9x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header pb-2">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Menu 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='completion-certs' class="link-unstyled">
          <i class="fas fa-award fa-9x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <div class="card-header pb-2">
        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Menu 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='self-certification' class="link-unstyled">
          <i class="fas fa-book-reader fa-9x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this.

```
<a #rla="routerLinkActive" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink='my-courses' class="link-unstyled">.... </a>
```

and on the card `div` you can use `[class.active-card]="rla.isActive"`

Comment: Thank you. But in my case since i have 3 cards, all the 3 cards get the styles applied.

Comment: Of course, add different ids for each card or check with a condition of rla.isActive === 'router link '